# Solving a diophantine equation by finding a parametrization of the solutions given several conditions

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

The diophantine equation that needs to be solved is $kx^2-y^2=3$ with the added conditions that:

\begin{cases}k>1\\k\text{ not a square}\\ x>2\\ x\equiv 0\mod 2\\ x/2 \not| \ k \\ x/2 \text{ is prime}\\y\ge 2a_0-1\ \text{for a given $a_0>1$ (If the general case is difficult, you can take $y\ge 3$)}\\ y\equiv 1\mod 2 \end{cases}

Does there exist solutions to this?

Is there a possibility of finding a parametrization of the solution space, given that there exists solutions?

Comment: I think you had better give some "solved" examples. Regarding $k$ as a fixed positiv e integer, but not a square, this is a Pell type equation. There is then a solution to $u^2 - k v^2 = 1$ with both $u,v > 0.$ If you have any solution with $x^2 - k y^2 = -3,$ there are infinitely many, and there is a parametrization since $3$ is prime. The best method for this is Conway's topograph method, I can recommend Weissman https://bookstore.ams.org/mbk-105/

Comment: What do you mean by solved examples?

Comment: Is it possible for me to add 2 more conditions to the question, now that two people have been kind enough to answer this? ( This is basically the last step of a problem so more I solve, more conditions pop out ). If possible, they can edit there answers to match the edited question.

Answer (score 1):

Some first solutions `(k,x,y)`:

```
(3, 26, 45)
(3, 362, 627)
(3, 5042, 8733)
(3, 978122, 1694157)
(3, 13623482, 23596563)
(3, 2642885282, 4577611587)
(3, 36810643322, 63757904493)
(7, 3554, 9403)
(7, 229282754, 606625147)
(13, 38, 137)
(13, 64019918, 230827097)
(13, 83097804242, 299613394073)
(13, 235877918665734054974882, 850469930499028549469753)
(13, 2558, 9223)
(13, 7261030735178798, 26180018628407143)
(19, 14, 61)
(19, 1618046, 7052899)
(19, 326, 1421)
(19, 58212830915038162905686, 253743847176071709170861)
(19, 10394892459533808328621849021359917860185446, 45310285760080830827611936996102170245034701)
(21, 218, 999)
(31, 112478, 626251)
(31, 9606423572322795038, 53486302820229129931)
(31, 403440540921333179011478355967103342785802477848069614588111812701806385189045719811347472294082, 2246261866262666012864719760793739267606071148451185317435025999508920483336608707247057823194229)
(31, 11444809546492688182289925351117269600732996230238, 63722002732338814173003541587996937892399972332469)
(43, 227130931995057031954322, 1489397123525004848544403)
(43, 337080667913715955918485976727628406446839914879210498774914453341665053163519836208869632882, 2210385757574850298935896273816634638801633432566733165530901396099108805499182673582660908973)
(57, 181802, 1372575)
(57, 1257971008703230617894211360345989359017195106582773200362641285924569052359886262478002, 9497472840079930484462970793563060761171890795258915962955791196319319692475807314746065)
(57, 26283927598839020682650813305905607574527174324691017444965284754736994179799687083828631687594958521115894002, 198439301679878069811130926108803717478981524427291823483067499793188412287726094922915734247247693843722716335)
(61, 413035544750178232595823135923756790534093014027366804367837286871356082, 3225910729523007988903114881402903248223687959185687368106315139614109881)
(67, 87496256453334584515305477442951892250181645325150378, 716187725288764979866262695585970715093455056431232115)
(73, 967051736423007670359794562776749987332865494312002, 8262493657913999506976513300454802755660072420143983)
(91, 39825838677019819923462482, 379914287433163942391892941)
(91, 3508617024811790339206810499872595695703523628815619544089898334077127836981891633770081052780930475169681943566129405137962, 33470073227268590546005555029142581164789218190438708947824181008307030893846673181194220150396669067094183968145496215416701)
(93, 14, 135)
(97, 11294, 111233)
(97, 86, 847)
(97, 10803245582, 106399629535)
```

gp-code:

```
 for(k=2, 100, if(!issquare(k),
  D= k; C= -3;
  Q= bnfinit('x^2-D, 1);
  fu= Q.fu[1]; \\print("Fundamental Unit: "fu);
  N= bnfisintnorm(Q, C); \\print("Fundamental Solutions (Norm): "N"\n");
  for(i=1, #N, n= N[i];
   for(j=0, 48,
    s= lift(n*fu^j);
    X= abs(polcoeff(s, 0)); Y= abs(polcoeff(s, 1));  
    if(Y, if(X==floor(X), if(Y==floor(Y), if(X^2-D*Y^2==C,
     p= Y/2;
     if(p==floor(p), if(isprime(p), if(k%p,
      y= X;
      if(y%2,
       print("("k", "2*p", "y")")
      )
     )))
    ))))
   )
  )
 ))
```

Answer (score 1):

You also have some computations by Dmitry; I suspect he put all your conditions into his program. I am just showing parametrized families with fixed $k$ of $w^2 - k v^2 = -3.$ The parametrization comes from first solving $r^2 - k s^2 = 1,$ using the smallest solution with $r,s > 0.$ When $k$ is not divisible by $3,$ there are two interlaced families, that is the quick description of the output saying "BACK ONE STEP"
Ummm; given $w^2 - k v^2 = -3,$ the "next" solution, either one or two lines after, comes from
$$ (w,v)  \mapsto (rw+ksv, \; sw + rv)  $$

anyway these are the values of $k$ below 29 that work..

```
 w^2 - 3 v^2 = -3 =  -3

Sat Apr  4 11:17:33 PDT 2020

w:  3  v:  2  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  0 ,  1
w:  12  v:  7
w:  45  v:  26
w:  168  v:  97
w:  627  v:  362
w:  2340  v:  1351
w:  8733  v:  5042
w:  32592  v:  18817
w:  121635  v:  70226
w:  453948  v:  262087
w:  1694157  v:  978122
w:  6322680  v:  3650401

Sat Apr  4 11:18:04 PDT 2020

 w^2 - 3 v^2 = -3 =  -3


====================================================

 w^2 - 7 v^2 = -3 =  -3

Sat Apr  4 11:20:31 PDT 2020

w:  2  v:  1  SEED   KEEP +- 
w:  5  v:  2  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  -2 ,  1
w:  37  v:  14
w:  82  v:  31
w:  590  v:  223
w:  1307  v:  494
w:  9403  v:  3554
w:  20830  v:  7873
w:  149858  v:  56641
w:  331973  v:  125474
w:  2388325  v:  902702
w:  5290738  v:  1999711

Sat Apr  4 11:20:52 PDT 2020

 w^2 - 7 v^2 = -3 =  -3


====================================================

 w^2 - 12 v^2 = -3 =  -3

Sat Apr  4 11:26:19 PDT 2020

w:  3  v:  1  SEED   KEEP +- 
w:  45  v:  13
w:  627  v:  181
w:  8733  v:  2521
w:  121635  v:  35113
w:  1694157  v:  489061

Sat Apr  4 11:26:34 PDT 2020

 w^2 - 12 v^2 = -3 =  -3


=============================================

 w^2 - 13 v^2 = -3 =  -3

Sat Apr  4 11:28:01 PDT 2020

w:  7  v:  2  SEED   KEEP +- 
w:  137  v:  38  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  -7 ,  2
w:  9223  v:  2558
w:  177833  v:  49322
w:  11971447  v:  3320282

Sat Apr  4 11:28:16 PDT 2020

 w^2 - 13 v^2 = -3 =  -3


=============================================



 w^2 - 19 v^2 = -3 =  -3

Sat Apr  4 11:30:43 PDT 2020

w:  4  v:  1  SEED   KEEP +- 
w:  61  v:  14  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  -4 ,  1
w:  1421  v:  326
w:  20744  v:  4759
w:  483136  v:  110839
w:  7052899  v:  1618046

Sat Apr  4 11:30:58 PDT 2020

 w^2 - 19 v^2 = -3 =  -3


===============================================



 w^2 - 21 v^2 = -3 =  -3

Sat Apr  4 11:32:41 PDT 2020

w:  9  v:  2  SEED   KEEP +- 
w:  999  v:  218
w:  109881  v:  23978
w:  12085911  v:  2637362

Sat Apr  4 11:32:56 PDT 2020

 w^2 - 21 v^2 = -3 =  -3





==================================================


 w^2 - 28 v^2 = -3 =  -3

Sat Apr  4 11:35:32 PDT 2020

w:  5  v:  1  SEED   KEEP +- 
w:  37  v:  7  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  -5 ,  1
w:  1307  v:  247
w:  9403  v:  1777
w:  331973  v:  62737
w:  2388325  v:  451351

Sat Apr  4 11:35:47 PDT 2020

 w^2 - 28 v^2 = -3 =  -3


=========================================================
```